# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

Tags: c#, .net

I am having following error 
Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

i have added Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll to GAC as well as in bin folder

Still having same exception.

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing and re-adding the reference.

Make sure that you are referencing the correct version of the Excel Interop - e.g. that you have version 12 in the references path location.

If the specificversion property is set, then it only looks for the version that has been added - worth checking properties of the reference such as copylocal aswell.

To find the version of excel, in visual studio, right click references, then extensions,then find the excel interop and check that the version is the one you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Interop assemblies are usually embedded to the assembly they're referenced from. You only need them during compilation. So adding them to the GAC or output folder both seems a bit odd to me.

I would suggest to just add the interop assembly to a specific folder within the project and re-add the reference. Make sure that "Embed Interop Types" is set to true, that the path is correct and that "Copy Local" is false.

Comment: installing 2007 Microsoft Office System Update: Redistributable Primary Interop Assemblies from  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346  solved problem

Answer (score 0):

When re-adding the reference, click the Advanced tab and uncheck "Reuse types in referenced assemblies". This will prevent the need to use a specified version of Excel.